# AWS Lambda functions - repository for multiple functions codes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, version-control, repository

#### How is it currently done the handling of multiple lambda functions for a single stack/application?

Considering a use case with more than one function is it better to stick all together in the same repository or have one for each?

Having a single repository for all the functions would be much easier for me coming from old/classic backend development with a single codebase for all the business logic, but moving on the AWS ecosystem means I can no longer "deploy" my entire business logic with a single command since I need to zip a single function and update the archive with the aws cli, and that is impossible with standard merge requests or pipeline due the impossibility of automation for these steps (every time it could be a different function or multiple ones).

From the other side, having e.g. 5 or 6 repositories one for each lambda alongside the ones for frontend and AWS stack would be very impractical to manage.

Answer (score 2):

Bundle your different lambda functions together as a Cloudformation stack. Cloudformation allows you to create multiple AWS services, bridge them together as you wish. There are many tools you can use to achieve this. AWS [Cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/index.html), AWS [SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) (serverless application model) or third party tools like [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) and [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/). Base concept is known as Infrastructure as Code (IAC).

As per respositories, you can have a single repository per stack. (AWS SAM provides sample codes with a good directory structure) You can try `sam init` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [AWS Serverless Application Model](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) for your development.  It allows you to bash script `build`, `package` and `deploy` using `sam` cli based on the yaml template.  SAM will figure out the diff in your code by itself (because it runs CloudFormation under the hood).  It allows not only to combine several functions into one package, but also add API gateways, dynamoDB tables and so much more!  Another cool feature is that your functions will appear as an integrated application in Lambda console so you can monitor them all at the same time.